# How can I see all the web service calls that are in a PHP/Zend site

Tags: php, web-services, zend-framework

Not sure if this is possible.  I have searched most of the afternoon.  Every search on anything related to "web services" returns  nothing i need.

I have a site that downloaded to my local machine.  Actually there are two sites.  Is there a method and/or tool out there that will show me the "web services" that are being called on a page as I click through the site?

I don't want to see the code or anything, I just want to see the "**web service**" name.

So for example, 
click on link one, i want something that will show me webser1a and webser2b were called
Click on link two, i want something that will show me webser12h and webser342cb were called.

You know if you use firebug or chrome developer tools, you can see the css files or js files - is there anything that can do this web services - again, i don't want to see the code as you actually with a css file via firebug, i just want to see that xxxx webservice(s) called.

Answer (score 0):

To check when web services are called in with Javascript, you can check the network tab in the Chrome Dev Tools (https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/network) or Firebug (http://getfirebug.com/network).

You will not see "the name of the web service" (whatever you mean by that?), but you can see which **url** is called (+ which data is posted, which is the answer of the web service, etc.)

Remember that you will only see the network traffic coming from your browser. The browser does not know anything about web service calls made by the backend code, deployed on a server.